# codeigniter not getting values from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

I have following `controllers, models & views` structure.

### controllers > (content.php)

```
class Content extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view("global_header");
        $this->load->model("ContentModel");
        $data['result'] = $this->ContentModel->blogPostContents();
        $this->load->view("content_page", $data);
        $this->load->view("global_footer");
    }
}
```

### models > (ContentModel.php)

```
class ContentModel extends CI_Model {

    public function blogPostContents() {
        $url_segment = $this->uri->segment(1); // Get post title

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('blog_posts');
        $this->db->where("url", $url_segment);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $query->result();
        $this->db->last_query();
        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

### views > (content_page.php)

```
<article>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <?php
                    echo $result[0]->post;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Now I have created another function in my controller file `content.php`:

```
public function show() {            
    $data['title'] = "Hello";
    $data['body'] = "World";
    $this->load->view('content_page', $data);
}
```

Now when I am trying to echo `$title & $body` variable inside content_page file I am getting variable is undefined. Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

**Error List:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: title

Filename: views/content_page.php

Line Number: 5
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: body

Filename: views/content_page.php

Line Number: 6
```

So I want to know how to display variable values to view.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify: `blogPostContents()` works ok, but `show()` returns the error?

Comment: `var_dump($result)` somewhere in view to see what structure you have got.

Comment: @GluePear Yes `blogPostContents()` is working perfect but `show()` returns errors. I have added error on my question.

Comment: @Tpojka `var_dump($result)` in `show()` function?

Comment: what url you are hitting ???

Comment: @php-baby in view of contact's index.

Answer (score 0):

In controller index () try adding this line:

```
class Content extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view("global_header");
    $this->load->model("ContentModel");
    $data['result'] = $this->ContentModel->blogPostContents();
    //$this->load->view("content_page", $data);
    $this->show($data);
    $this->load->view("global_footer");
}

}
```

In show method or function

```
public function show($data) {            
    $data['title'] = "Hello";
    $data['body'] = "World";
    $this->load->view('content_page', $data);
}
```

Hope it works fine